# Excel VBA search for a word in a column and copy the row below the word onto a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a macro to open a workbook, search for the word Apples and then copy the first row below the word onto a new workbook. Everything is in column A and the word "Apples" comes up on multiple rows. This code currently takes the word Apple & the row below and moves it onto another sheet. I want it to move to another workbook and take just the row below. For some reason it also grabs 2 unwanted lines at the end. I been fiddling with it but am not sure where to go from here.

```
Sub Apples()

    Date1 = Range("B3").Value

    ChDir "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\" & Date1
    Workbooks.OpenText Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\" & Date1 & "\File" & Left(Date1, 4), Origin:= _
        437, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
        , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

    Windows("Apples" & Left(Date1, 4)).Activate
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Const fWhat As String = "Apples"
    Dim R As Range, fAdr As String, nR As Long, cutRng As Range, Ar As Range, i As Long, delAdr As String
    With Sheets("Apples" & Left(Date1, 4))
    Set R = .Range("A:A").Find(fWhat, [A1], xlFormulas, xlPart, , , False)
    If Not R Is Nothing Then
        fAdr = R.Address
        Set cutRng = R.Offset(0, 0).Resize(4, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
        Do
            Set R = .Range("A:A").FindNext(R)
            If R Is Nothing Then Exit Do
            If R.Address = fAdr Then Exit Do
            Set cutRng = Union(cutRng, R.Offset(0, 0).Resize(4, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
        Loop
    End If
    If Not cutRng Is Nothing Then
        delAdr = cutRng.Address
        nR = 1
        For Each Ar In cutRng.Areas
            Ar.Cut Destination:=Sheets(.Index + 1).Range("A" & nR)
            nR = Sheets(.Index + 1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Next Ar
        .Range(delAdr).Delete shift:=xlUp
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to COPY the row below? Your code is CUTTING the row containing apples and DELETING that row. Also, why are you using an offset of 4 .. see '.Resize(4,...'? Given rows with Apples, Pears, Apples, Plums, what do you want to happen? Copy Pears and Plums to the new sheet?

Comment: Yes copy Apples and Pears onto a new workbook, at the moment it is copying to a new sheet

Comment: Does the 'new' workbook already exist? If so, where and what name? If not, what is it's name supposed to be and where? Sheet name? And does this VBA code really need to open a different workbook to get to the source rows, or can it run in the same workbook that contains the data to search?

Comment: The new workbook does not exist and it can be named the default book1. The purpose is because I need to end up using this macro for a total of 6 documents and end up cutting and pasting it in the new workbook on sheet 1. So each workbook will get its own column from A to F. I figure I could try to make the macro for 1 document and edit for the other 5, then call all 6 macros at once. I guess the part I really need help with is how do I make it open a new workbook and cut it into that instead of onto a new sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Corrected code to get two rows each time; and to copy as encountered rather than waiting until end.

The following is a modified version of your code. It opens the workbook that has your 'data', then creates a new workbook (no provision for managing if existing name found), then copies the row with the search term plus the next row. You indicated it only needs to copy the FIRST it finds.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Apples()
Dim wbThis      As Workbook
Dim wbData      As Workbook
Dim wbNew       As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim Date1       As String
Dim strPath     As String
Const fWhat     As String = "Apples"
Dim rngR        As Range, copyRng As Range, rngA As Range
Dim strAdr      As String
Dim lNextRow    As Long, i As Long
Dim bFound      As Boolean
Dim rngFirst     As Range

    Date1 = Range("B3").value

    strPath = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\"
    strPath = "C:\temp\"                    ' *** DELETE THIS LINE

    ChDir strPath & Date1

    ' Open Workbook which has the data
    Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & Date1 & "\File" & Left(Date1, 4))

    ' Make sure we have the desired Worksheet Name
    bFound = False
    For Each ws In wbData.Worksheets
        If ws.Name = "Apples" & Left(Date1, 4) Then
            bFound = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next ws
    If bFound = False Then
        MsgBox "Workbook '" & strPath & Date1 & "\File" & Left(Date1, 4) & _
            "' does not contain the expected sheet named '" & "Apples" & Left(Date1, 4) & "'." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Please correct and start over.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Missing Sheet"
        wbData.Close
        GoTo WrapUp
    End If

    ' Create New workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbNew.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "Book123.xlsx"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    lNextRow = 0
    Debug.Print "--------------------"
    With wbData.Sheets("Apples" & Left(Date1, 4))
        Set rngR = .Range("A:A").Find(fWhat, [A1], xlFormulas, xlPart, , , False)

        If Not rngR Is Nothing Then
            Set rngFirst = rngR
            Debug.Print "First: " & rngR.Address
            lNextRow = 1
            If Not rngR Is Nothing Then
                strAdr = rngR.Address
                Set copyRng = rngR.Offset(0, 0).Resize(2, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
                Debug.Print "Copy: " & copyRng.Address
                copyRng.Copy Destination:=wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lNextRow)
                lNextRow = lNextRow + 2

                Do
                    Set rngR = .Range("A:A").FindNext(rngR)
                    If rngR Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    Debug.Print "Next : " & rngR.Address

                    If rngR.Address = strAdr Then Exit Do
                    Set copyRng = rngR.Offset(0, 0).Resize(2, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
                    Debug.Print "Copy: " & copyRng.Address
                    copyRng.Copy Destination:=wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lNextRow)
                    lNextRow = lNextRow + 2
                    'Debug.Print "Combo Before: " & copyRng.Address
                    'Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, rngR.Offset(0, 0).Resize(2, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                    'Set copyRng = Union(copyRng, rngR.Offset(0, 0).Resize(2, .UsedRange.Columns.Count))
                    'Debug.Print "Combo After : " & copyRng.Address
                Loop
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox " not Found"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    wbData.Close
    wbNew.Close

WrapUp:
    ' Close it down...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank I got the code to work, the only problem is that lets say I have "Apples" come up 10 times in column A, It is only copying and pasting "Apples" and the row below it once. It should come up 10 times with 10 rows under for a total of 20 rows. Is it not looping ?

Comment: Can cell A1 contain the search word?

Comment: On the new workbook? Yes it can. If you asking if the search word ever shows up on A1 of the original then no, it usually doesn't show up until after row 3.

Comment: I tried to replace all the copy with CUT to see if it will just cut the data out but it gave me errors. The final list on the new workbook should say Apple, Pears, Apple, Pears, Apple, Pears, how many time Apple shows up all in Column A, 1 word per row.

Comment: I just replaced the code in the Answer (corrected the issue you found and simplified the copy process). I set the code to copy all columns for the row with 'Apples' plus the following row. If that is not correct, then it can easily be changed.

Comment: I ended up fiddling with the code and got it to work. Thank you very much for helping me.